# Definition of an Open set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

So from notes I'm reading, the definiton of an open set is "A subset X ⊂ (a, b) is called open in (a, b) if for every c ∈ X there is an interval (a′, b′) such that (a′, b′) ⊂ X and c ∈ (a′, b′)."

I tend to understand better using examples, so if I were to give an intervel of (a= -5, b=5), then X could be {-4,3,4}. From what I understand, this would be an open set as for each element(or c) in x, there is an interval (for -4 you could have (a=-4,b=3) and for 3 you could have (a=0,b=4)) in which a and b are not 5/-5. But if X was {-5,0,5} then I presume it can't be an open set because for any interval given, a and be would have to be -5 and 5 respectively.

Is my understanding correct here?

Comment: For $c=-4$ you choosed $(-4,3)$ which is NOT contained in $\{-4,3,4\}$ and does NOT satisfies $-4 \in (-4,3)$

Comment: Oh ok, so the -4 and 3 aren't within the interval. So if I chose a set like {-3,0,3}, that would be an open set? And so in this case, as long as the subset doesn't contain -4 or 4, it can be an open set?

Comment: If the set is $X=\{-3,0,3\}$,  can you find an interval contained in $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not right.

I think the most telling evidence of misunderstanding here is that you're starting with the interval $(a, b)$, then considering $X$ that "fit" this interval in some way. Really, it's the other way around. You start with a set $X$ that you wish to show is open, you then consider an arbitrary point $c$ in this set $X$, and finally, you build an interval $(a, b)$, contained in $X$, but that also contains $c$, i.e. $c \in (a, b) \subseteq X$. This interval $(a, b)$ will change depending on which $c \in X$ you choose, so it's not unreasonable for $a$ and $b$ to be functions of $c$.

In the examples you gave, $X$ is a set with $3$ elements. None of these sets are open! As an example, take $X = \{-4, 3, 4\}$. If this were open, I should be able to take any point $c \in X$, and find $a < b$ so that $c \in (a, b) \subseteq X$. Because $X$ is non-empty (i.e. we can choose such a $c \in X$), this implies there must be an open interval contained in $X$. But this is not the case, as $X$ contains just $3$ points, whereas an interval $(a, b)$ contains infinitely many!

More concretely, if we were to take $c = 3$, assume we could find $(a, b)$ such that $3 \in (a, b) \subseteq X$. Note that $3 \in (a, b)$ means $a < 3 < b$. Let's consider two cases: either $4 \in (a, b)$ or $4 \notin (a, b)$. If $4 \in (a, b)$, then we get $a < 3 < 4 < b$, and any points between $3$ and $4$, e.g. $3.5$, will also be between $a$ and $b$. But, since we assumed $(a, b) \subseteq X$, we know that $3.5 \in X$ as well, which violates the definition of $X$.

In the other case, if $4 \notin (a, b)$, then $a < 3 < b < 4$. Consider the midpoint $\frac{b + 3}{2}$, which lies between $3$ and $b$. It therefore lies between $a$ and $b$, so $\frac{b + 3}{2} \in (a, b)$, and thus it must lie in $X$. As $-4 < 3 < \frac{b + 3}{2} < b < 4$, this means it cannot be $-4$, $3$, or $4$, so, once again, we have a contradiction: we've discovered a new point that does not fit the definition of $X$, but under our assumption, must lie within $X$.

---

For contrast, here's an example of an open set:
$$X = (4, \infty).$$
To prove this is open, consider any point $c \in (4, \infty)$, which is to say, $c > 4$. We must now construct an interval $(a, b)$ so that
$$c \in (a, b) \subseteq X.$$
Note that $a < c < b$ in order for $c \in (a, b)$, and so that we have $(a, b) \subseteq X = (4, \infty)$, we also need $4 \le a$ (yes, less than or equal to, since both $(a, b)$ and $(4, \infty)$ have open endpoints, it's not a problem if $4 = a$). Putting it together, we get
$$4 \le a < c < b.$$
These are the only requirements we have to satisfy! Remember too that our $a$ and $b$ are allowed to vary with respect to $c$. We could choose any $b$ that is greater than $c$, e.g. $b = c + 1$ (or $b = c + 36$ would work just as well!). For $a$, there's no reason not to just choose $a = 4$. So, for any $c \in (4, \infty)$, i.e. $c > 4$, we see that
$$c \in (4, c + 1) \subseteq X = (4, \infty).$$
This proves $X$ is open.